# How can I send a command to X number of EC2 instances via SSH

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, ssh, cmd, python-multiprocessing

I've a lot AWS EC2 Instances and I need to execute a python script from them at the same time.

I've been trying from my pc to execute the script by sending via ssh the commands required. For this, I've created a another python script that open a cmd terminal and then execute some commands (the ones I need to execute the python script on each instance). Since I need that all these cmd terminal are openned at the same time I've used the ThreatPoolExecutor that (with my PC characteristics) grants me 60 runs in parallel. This is the code:

```
import os
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

ipAddressesList=list(open("hosts.txt").read().splitlines())

def functionMain(threadID):
    os.system(r'start cmd ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i mysshkey.pem ec2-user@'+ipAddressesList[threadID]+' "cd scripts && python3.7 script.py"')

functionMainList =list(range(0,len(ipAddressesList)))

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:

    results = executor.map(functionMain, functionMainList)
```

The problem of this is that the command that executes the `script.py` is blocking the terminal until the end of the process, hence the functionMain stays waiting for the result. I would like to find the way that after sending the command `python3.7 script.py` the function ends but the script keeps executing in the instance. So the pool executor can continue with the threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) can be used to run scripts on multiple Amazon EC2 instances (and even on-premises computers if they have the Systems Manager agent installed).

The Run Command can also provide back results of the commands run on each instance.

This is definitely preferably to connecting to the instances via SSH to run commands.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is it posible to run a documment type "AWS-RunShellScript" for more than 50 targets? I need to run the same command in 1000 instances.

Comment: Not sure. Here's a reference to limits, but it might be per-instance rather than the number of instances: [python - AWS Systems Manager "In Progress" commands limit to 5? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707807/aws-systems-manager-in-progress-commands-limit-to-5). Service quotas are listed in: [AWS Systems Manager endpoints and quotas - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ssm.html#limits_ssm). Where did you see a limit of 50?

Comment: When using the Run Command GUI (not via command in AWS cloudshell) at the point of selecting targets manually. It is set a limit of 50 instances. Anyways I ll try to contact Amazon because I ll need to upgrade my account since I am using the free tier.

Comment: The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is a billing discount. It provides a certain amount of services at no charge. However, your account is a "full account", not a "free account". There is no such thing as an account "upgrade", since all accounts are the same. Some portions of the Free Tier apply only during the first 12 months of an account, and some portions apply always.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for not providing a "code" answer, but I believe there are existing tools that already solve this problem. This sounds like an ideal use of [ClusterShell](https://clustershell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html):

> ClusterShell provides a light and unified command execution Python framework to help administer GNU/Linux or BSD clusters. Some of the most important benefits of using ClusterShell are to:
>
> - provide an efficient, parallel and highly scalable command execution engine in Python,

Using `clush` you can execute commands in parallel across many nodes. It has options for grouping the output by hostname as well.

Another option would be to use [Ansible](https://ansible.com/), but you'll need to create a playbook in that case whereas with ClusterShell you are running a command the same way you would with SSH. With Ansible, you will create a target group for a playbook and it will connect up to each instance and tell it to run the playbook. To make it disconnect while the command is still running, look into [asynchronous](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html) actions:

> By default Ansible runs tasks synchronously, holding the connection to the remote node open until the action is completed. This means within a playbook, each task blocks the next task by default, meaning subsequent tasks will not run until the current task completes. This behavior can create challenges. For example, a task may take longer to complete than the SSH session allows for, causing a timeout. Or you may want a long-running process to execute in the background while you perform other tasks concurrently. Asynchronous mode lets you control how long-running tasks execute.

I've used both of these in HPC environments with more than 5,000 machines and they both will work well for your purpose.